# Delete Artifactory Build using REST API

Tags: artifactory

As part of my custom promotion process I want to get rid of older builds of the SNAPSHOT versions. When I trigger a build delete using the artifactory rest API using the 'artifacts=1' flag the artifacts itself are deleted successfully, but the according directories where the artifacts have been stored are still there. Is there a convenient way to delete those empty directories too during the build delete operation?

cheers,

René

Answer (score 2):

The directories aren't deleted by default. You can write a user plugin to delete empty folders as afterDelete trigger. Here's an example: https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/cleanup/deleteEmptyDirs/deleteEmptyDirs.groovy

Comment: I saw that script already but I thought there might be something I had missed. thanks!